# How to use rr.edata in MyDns for DKIM?

Tags: dkim

I have got MyDns server v1.2.8.31 under PostgreSQL and I want write TXT record for DKIM into Database without using admin.php and other tools.

How to use rr.edata and rr.edatakey in MyDns for DKIM?
Which psql queries should be for correct insert data?

How to enable rr.edata in Mydns and what I should do with rr.data field?

Answer (score 1):

You should first activate this option in your mydns.conf :

`extended-data-support = yes`

After that you can recreate your database structure with :

`mydns --create-tables | mysql -u root -p mydns`

If you already have data, then adjust the mysql scheme with :

`alter table rr add column edata blob;`

`alter table rr add column edatakey char(32) DEFAULT NULL;`

To use it directly in your code, you should detect if data is longer than you data field, if it's the case you should split data : a first split going to the classic data field, the second going the the edata field(which is a blob so can be very long), you should also md5sum the edata to put it in the edatakey.

If help needed you can consult the code on admin.php provided in the contrib repository of the source package.